# onclick window.location.href with input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onchange, window.location

I have an input and I want the user to be sent to another page with the input's value in the URI so that I can extract it.

This is how my input is set up:

```
<input name="date" id="datepicker" onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Date=' + document.getElementById("datepicker").value;">
```

Basically, when the date is changed, the date should be added onto the end of the URI and the user should be sent to test.php, where the value will be extracted. However, the value doesn't seem to be added on.

What's the problem?

Comment: you need to use single quotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
<input name="date" id="datepicker" onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Date=' + this.value;">
```

You don't need to do `document.getElementById('datepicker')` since the element you are in is already the one you want the value from.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy with the solution.

Comment: I will, I just have to wait 10 minutes because you were so quick!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using double-quotes to delimit the attribute value *and* the string value within the `onchange` event. Try using single-quotes, like this:

```
<input name="date" id="datepicker" onchange="window.location.href = 'test.php?Date=' + document.getElementById('datepicker').value;">
```

And of course, since you've tagged the question with jQuery, why not use it?

```
<input name="date" id="datepicker">

...

$("#datepicker").change(function() { 
    window.location.href = 'test.php?Date=' + this.value;
});
```